# CSS3 get last element

Tags: css, css-selectors

How I can get the last element (hr) from the following code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span class="hr"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="hr"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span class="hr"></span> <!-- I need this -->
    </div>
</div>
```

`.hr:last-child` doesn't work for this.

Of course, DOM structure could be more complicated. I just need to fetch the last needed element.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear; there are several ways to get the last `.hr` element from your example, but you say "DOM structure could be more complicated." In order to answer your question, you need to mention what possible DOM structures you could have; in some it might be possible, in some it will not be.

Here is one way to get the `.hr` out of the last `div`:

```
div div:last-of-type .hr
```

Here's another way to get the `.hr` out of the last child of the outer `div`:

```
div :last-child .hr
```

If you need to get the last `.hr` element out of the document, regardless of what it's inside, then you can't do that in CSS. In CSS, you can only select the first, last, or *n*th element at one particular level of the hierarchy, you can't select the last element of some type regardless of what it's nested in.

Comment: Great post. `dless of what it's inside, then you can't do that in CSS`, 5 years later, is this still the same though? Just curious, thanks!

Comment: I don't believe anything has changed with regards to this. [CSS Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-nth-child-pseudo) extends the `:nth-last-child()` and `:nth-last-of-type()` to allow specifying an additional selector constraining the set of elements that you are matching against, so you could select the last element with class `.hr` out of a set of siblings with `:nth-last-child(1 of .hr)`. They don't allow selecting over all elements in the document, however, just out of siblings of a common parent element. And I think no browsers yet support this syntax; it's a draft

Comment: [Previous drafts of CSS Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#the-nth-last-match-pseudo) had a `:nth-last-match(1 of .hr)` pseudo-class that would do what the original question asked, but it was removed, probably for being impractical to implement.

Comment: Ah, I midunderstood. `:nth-match` and `:nth-last-match` have just been replaced with the new syntax for `:nth-child`; they were never for selecting arbitrary descendents, just siblings of a single parent. See [this message](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Jan/0607.html) for the explanation: "I think \[:nth-child() is\] more clear. :nth-match() could be interpreted as matching against the tree, not just against children"

Answer (score 8):

```
div:last-child .hr
```

Comment: Then you should place something like a `class` on those containing `div` elements to identify that type of element. Once that is done, change `div` to `.class`.

Answer (score 3):

The following selector should work:

```
div *:last-child *:last-child
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/78w3bofg/1/