# Select last element from already selected elements in pure css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want something like jquery `:last` selector, but in pure css.

How can i get only 'z' paragraph, **if i didn't know its index in DOM structure!**.
or how get last child of class '.area'?
I see this [CSS3 get last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740949/css3-get-last-element) , but it doesnt work in my case, because i have another childs in parent element.

`p.area:last-child` donesn't work!

I found a solution, when we know how many elements will be with class `.area`.

Selector looks like this: `p.area ~ p.area ~ p.area`
But when we didn't know ... I think...
just for fun =)

```
<div>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p class="">The first paragraph.</p>
<p class="area">The x paragraph.</p>
<p class="area">The y paragraph.</p>
<p class="area">The z paragraph.</p>
<p class="">The last paragraph.</p>

</div
```

Comment: It would be nice to know what browsers are you expecting this to work in? IE8+ ?

Comment: See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i

Comment: do you know how many area elements there are?

Comment: I assume this is a randomly generated list if you are not able to know where it will be located in the DOM correct?

Comment: yes, i dont know how many elements with class '.area' and i dont know its indexes in DOM structure.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the HTML? Are `.area` elements always generated in a block? If so, maybe wrap them in a div instead of tagging each `p`.

Answer (score 6):

You cant do it without javascript. Here is a quote from [the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos):

> Standalone text and other non-element nodes are not counted when
>   calculating the position of an element in the list of children of its
>   parent.

Pseudo-classes target elements that can't be targeted with combinators or simple selectors like id or class.  These types of pseudo classes are called "[Structural Pseudo Classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos)". They will ignore the fact that there is a class on the element and simply use the DOM to determine the correct element to target.

Your only options are explicit targeting with nth-child or javascript in this instance.

Comment: `Pseudo classes target the element and not the class or ID` That's absolutely wrong as `.area:last-of-type` works **[in this case](http://jsbin.com/iwotob/1/edit)**, the term of `element` is refers to that element you can select by a selector in the DOM. check also my comment below the @Chris' answer.

Comment: You're wrong, it is using the selector to get the element. That is the last p in that list. Try adding another p with no class to that example and it will break. Also, in the comment on Chris's answer that is the last article element, again using the selector to find the element.

Comment: I know, but again I emphasize that this statement `Pseudo classes target the element and not the class or ID` is wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811962/how-to-css-select-element-based-on-inner-html (not possible in css)

Comment: @MatthewR. +1 for revising the answer. And sorry, I'm on `"use strict"` mode ;)

Comment: And also it would be great to mention that `Most of those structural (except :root and :empty) pseudo-elements represents the element that is the child or one of its type in the list of children of its parent element` :)

Comment: @Hashem Qolami: The original statement wasn't wrong. A class/ID is simply a property of an element. Every simple selector matches on a per-element basis, pseudo-classes included.

Comment: @Hashem Qolami: As for your last comment, pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes are two different things. Please do not mix these up.

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, my bad. I meant pseudo-classes not elements. but about that sentence, as you said: `A class/ID is simply a property of an element`, and what I wanted was changing the statement in order to indicate this fact better. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 0):

you should use nth child, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) how it works.
In your case, it should be:

```
p.area:nth-child(5){
your style here;
}
```

For browser support look [here](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3).

Comment: "If i didn't know its index in DOM structure"

Comment: Sorry, I saw only the code and the request, didn't read the full description although the phrase you quoted was bold :).