# Select first and last element of sequences with specific class in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a lot of divs having class `line` with `strong.datum` element within. I would need to highlight first and last element of each sequence with class `.active`. If it is not possible to do it with CSS, is there any chance to do it via jQuery?

In this example should have class `.start` elements `.dt_26, .dt_66, .dt_27, .dt_77` and class `.end` should have elements `.dt_46, .dt_76, .dt_57 and .dt_97`.

```
<div class="line">
<strong class="dt_16 app_54 datum">1.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_26 app_54 datum active">2.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_36 app_54 datum active">3.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_46 app_54 datum active">4.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_56 app_54 datum">5.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_66 app_54 datum active">6.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_76 app_54 datum active">7.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_86 app_54 datum active">8.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_96 app_54 datum active">9.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_106 app_54 datum">10.6.</strong>
</div>
<div class="line">
<strong class="dt_17 app_54 datum">1.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_27 app_54 datum active">2.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_37 app_54 datum active">3.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_47 app_54 datum active">4.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_57 app_54 datum active">5.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_67 app_54 datum">6.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_77 app_54 datum">7.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_87 app_54 datum active">8.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_97 app_54 datum active">9.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_107 app_54 datum">10.7.</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: `first()` and `last()`

Comment: duplicated, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740949/css3-get-last-element

Comment: @AlexAngelico Not a dupe; the question there's a bit different and the answers significantly different.

Comment: @PranavCBalan, But I would need to highlight 2.6., 4.6., 6.6. and 9.6. (in first line), because 5.6. has no class "active". That's kind of "tricky" in my question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a jQuery solution...

Using [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), you can loop through all the `.line` [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) elements and check if they're first or last.

I even made an addition for the fun of it... You also can check if they're *"lonely"*... ;)

As you can see, the code is pretty self explanatory...

```js
$(".line").children().each(function(){

  // Firsts
  if( $(this).hasClass("active") && !$(this).prev().hasClass("active") ){
    $(this).addClass("first");
  }
  
  // Lasts
  if( $(this).hasClass("active") && !$(this).next().hasClass("active") ){
    $(this).addClass("last");
  }
  
  // Lonelies
  if( $(this).hasClass("active") && !$(this).prev().hasClass("active") && !$(this).next().hasClass("active") ){
    $(this).removeClass("first last").addClass("alone");
  }
});
```

```css
.first{
  color: green;
}
.last{
  color: orange;
}
.alone{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="line">
  <strong class="dt_16 app_54 datum">1.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_26 app_54 datum active">2.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_36 app_54 datum active">3.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_46 app_54 datum active">4.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_56 app_54 datum">5.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_66 app_54 datum active">6.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_76 app_54 datum active">7.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_86 app_54 datum active">8.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_96 app_54 datum active">9.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_106 app_54 datum">10.6.</strong>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <strong class="dt_17 app_54 datum">1.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_27 app_54 datum active">2.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_37 app_54 datum active">3.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_47 app_54 datum active">4.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_57 app_54 datum active">5.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_67 app_54 datum">6.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_77 app_54 datum">7.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_87 app_54 datum active">8.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_97 app_54 datum">9.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_107 app_54 datum">10.7.</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK You can't select the first and last element *with additional requirements (like with specific class etc)* via css.  Fairly easy with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".line").each(function(i, line) {
    $(line).children("strong.active:first, strong.active:last").addClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line">
<strong class="dt_16 app_54 datum">1.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_26 app_54 datum active">2.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_36 app_54 datum active">3.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_46 app_54 datum active">4.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_56 app_54 datum">5.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_66 app_54 datum active">6.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_76 app_54 datum active">7.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_86 app_54 datum active">8.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_96 app_54 datum active">9.6.</strong>
<strong class="dt_106 app_54 datum">10.6.</strong>
</div>
<div class="line">
<strong class="dt_17 app_54 datum">1.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_27 app_54 datum active">2.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_37 app_54 datum active">3.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_47 app_54 datum active">4.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_57 app_54 datum active">5.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_67 app_54 datum">6.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_77 app_54 datum">7.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_87 app_54 datum active">8.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_97 app_54 datum active">9.7.</strong>
<strong class="dt_107 app_54 datum">10.7.</strong>
</div>
```

The reason this works and something like:

```
.line > strong.active:first {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

doesn't work is because the jQuery parsing engine is not exactly the same as CSS selectors.  [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) in jQuery just selects the first element after selectors, where-as `:first` is css literally means the first element regardless of selectors, so (CSS) if your selectors remove the literal-first element then `:first` never matches.

Comment: Thank you, but I would need to highlight also 4.6. and 6.6. (in first line), because 5.6. has no class "active". That's kind of "tricky" in my question :(

Answer (score 1):

It's not *exactly* possible in CSS - so here is a vanilla JS solution - see explanations inline:

```js
// get a list of line elemnts
[...document.querySelectorAll('.line')].forEach(function(line) {
  // reduce the child elements
  [...line.querySelectorAll('strong')].reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (c.classList.contains('active')) {
      if(!p) // mark first
        c.classList.add('first');
       // mark last after checking the following child
      if((!c.nextElementSibling || !c.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('active')) && p)
        c.classList.add('last');
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, false);
})
```

```css
.first {
  color: cadetblue;
}

.last {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <strong class="dt_16 app_54 datum">1.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_26 app_54 datum active">2.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_36 app_54 datum active">3.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_46 app_54 datum active">4.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_56 app_54 datum">5.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_66 app_54 datum active">6.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_76 app_54 datum active">7.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_86 app_54 datum active">8.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_96 app_54 datum active">9.6.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_106 app_54 datum">10.6.</strong>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <strong class="dt_17 app_54 datum">1.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_27 app_54 datum active">2.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_37 app_54 datum active">3.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_47 app_54 datum active">4.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_57 app_54 datum active">5.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_67 app_54 datum">6.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_77 app_54 datum">7.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_87 app_54 datum active">8.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_97 app_54 datum active">9.7.</strong>
  <strong class="dt_107 app_54 datum">10.7.</strong>
</div>
```